# ReferenceError: Request is not defined - during E2E testing NestJS project

Tags: nestjs, e2e-testing, supertest

I have a NestJsS project with a lot of controllers and I want to test it with Supertest as described here: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing

But if I create a controller that has a method where I inject request with Req() I get this error:

```
 FAIL  test/app.e2e-spec.ts
 Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: Request is not defined

   5 | export class AuthController {
   6 |   @Get()
>  7 |   getAll(@Req() request: Request) {
     |                          ^
   8 |     console.log('### AuthController.getAll()');
   9 |   }
  10 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/auth/auth.controller.ts:7:26)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/auth/auth.module.ts:2:1)
```

You can simply reproduce this issue if you create a new project, then try to run E2E test with

```
yarn test:e2e
```

First, it works, but if you create any controller which has a method with @Req() parameter, you get the error above.

Why? How can I fix it?

I thought Nest solved this issue, documentation wrote this:
"Nest makes it easy to use the Supertest library to simulate HTTP requests."

Comment: Can you provide the e2e code?

Comment: I found the root cause of the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found root cause of this issue.

My controller contained this method:

```
@Get()
getAll(@Req() request: Request) {
  console.log('### AuthController.getAll()');
}
```

but I forgot to import Request from Express:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
```

Request interface is contained by TypeScript, so I didn't have a compilation error.

Solution:
either import Request from express
or don't use Request type:

```
@Get()
getAll(@Req() request: any) {
  console.log('### AuthController.getAll()');
}
```